# O boletim da comunidade sumiu!

Tags: bug, status-pronto, boletim-da-comunidade

O *box* **Boletim da Comunidade** – que lista discussões do meta com a tag [destaque](/questions/tagged/destaque) e outras escolhidas pelo algoritmo de *hot questions* – **desapareceu** da home do site!

Alguém poderia trazê-lo de volta, por favor? É difícil atrair usuários para o meta, e sem o boletim acho que fica mais difícil ainda.

Comment: A sidebar tá muito estranha. Isso de *Tags recentes* e *Medalhas recentes* é totalmente antigo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A new feature introduced uncovered a bad configuration in the system. I've corrected the configuration and will investigate further.